# Limit date range on ASP.NET InputDate component

Tags: asp.net, date, .net-6.0

I am using a date input on a Blazor page with .NET 6.0:

```
<InputDate @bind-Value="_newItem.StartDate" />
```

Is there any way to set a minimum date , i.e. prevent the user from entering dates before a certain date?  I have tried adding a parameter `min="2023-05-01"` as would be supported by  `<input type="date">`  but it is ignored by `InputDate`.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't found any way to do this in the control itself; but containing the value via a Setter for the two-way binding item appears to produce the desired effect:

```
public class TheData
{
    public DateTime StartDate { get { return _startDate; } set { _setStartDate(value); } }
    public DateTime MinimumStartDate { get; set; } = DateTime.Now.Date.AddDays(1);
    private DateTime _startDate = default;
    private void _setStartDate(DateTime v)
    {
         _startDate = (v.Date < MinimumStartDate ? MinimumStartDate : v.Date);
    }
}
```

If an out of bounds value is selected then the picker reverts to the actual value set by the set function.